# Empty RDL Report when saving to Reports Entity in Dynamics 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have created an RDL in a Report Server Project in Visual Studio 2015. I simply used a Fetch XML from Dynamics and inserted it as my query in the RDL.

```
    <fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="q_qentity">
    <attribute name="q_jid" />
    <attribute name="q_titlename" />
    <attribute name="q_titlecode" />
    <attribute name="q_surveyid" />
    <attribute name="q_approveddate" />
    <attribute name="q_fiscalyear" />
    <attribute name="q_qentityid" />
    <attribute name="s_type" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="createdby" />
    <attribute name="createdonbehalfby" />
    <order attribute="q_jid" descending="false" />
    <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="q_jid" operator="eq" value="285" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

On Visual Studio it runs fine, however when I save it into Reports Entity and try to run this is what I get:

[image]

I also embedded the Data Source since I read online Shared Data Source gives issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download an existing (and working) RDL from your instance.
Modify that RDL, maybe a simple table report and upload as a new report record.
If that works use that RDL as your report template.